# Searching locations with name in google maps sdk in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using Google map sdk in my project. I have search bar at top and I have to search the location that user enter in that search bar. Secondly search bar should give hints like if we search location in Google maps application.Any help will be appreciate able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Prerequisites**

1. [Google Places API KEY](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/signup)

[Get Started with GOOGLE PLACE API on iOS](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/start)

**STEPS**

1. You need to create an url using the text entered in your textfield.
2. Append the text from textfield the create an url like this

   NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=%@&key=%s",queryText,kGooglePlaceAPIKey]];

where **queryText** is the ***text***, and **kGooglePlaceAPIKey** is your ***GOOGLE PLACES API KEY***.

3. Do JSON Parsing on this URL.
4. You will get the information of all location related to the text entered in your textfield.

*Figure : JSON Response on Firefox Browser using JSONViewer Addon*

[image: JSON Response on Firefox Browser]

FOR MORE INFORMATION REFER THIS SITE : [**Google Places Text Search Requests**](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)

Hope it helps You
Cheers
:)